# Ruby Spring startup problems - too long unix socket path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, sockets

I'm having problems getting Spring running with my Rails project. Each time I run spring to start it up it gives me the following error:

```
> spring rspec spec/models

==> lib/spring/server.rb:40:in 'initialize': too long unix socket path (110bytes given but 104bytes max) (ArgumentError)
```

Any ideas? My tests run fine without spring.

I'm running:

- OSX 10.8.4
- ruby 1.9.3-p392
- rails( 3.2.10)
- spring (0.0.10)
- rack (1.4.5)

Comment: you should file an issue on github

Comment: That's a good idea, done. I will leave this open until I have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11640

This works for me

```bash
git config --global core.fsmonitor false
```